# Two switches in one junction box

Tags: wiring

[image: wiri]

I have a junction box with two switches in it.  I have found some interesting wiring in this house, but I am not sure what to do with this. The switch on the left has two red wires going to it and one white.  The other has two blacks.  There is also another three way switch I believe is wired into this circuit.  Any ideas on what this set up is?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Figure out if I should be using a three way switch for the one with two red wires, and a single pole for the one using two black wires.  Solely going by the number of wires I would do that, but the fact that the colors are off is making my question that.

Answer (score 1):

### Never mind the wire colors

Since Romex is limited to red/white/black and the occasional blue, you pretty much have to ignore colors when dealing with wiring, save for white often but not always being neutral and green or bare almost always being ground.

### As to decoding your box (grounds omitted since we know what they do :)

- LR (Left-hand Red): This is the switched-hot going out to whatever the 3-way controls -- it will land on the differently-colored (usually black) screw on the 3-way switch.
- LB (Left-hand Black): This is the incoming always-hot -- it goes to the black bundle with MB and the pigtail to the single pole switch.
- LW (Left-hand White): This is the incoming neutral -- it goes to the white bundle with RW.
- MR (Middle Red): This is a traveler wire between the two three-way switches -- it lands on one of the two same colored (usually brass) screws on the 3-way switch.
- MB (Middle Black): This is the always-hot out to the other 3-way switch, forming an old-style switch loop with the two travelers in the middle cable.
- MW (Middle White): This is the other traveler wire between the two three-way switches -- it lands on the other same colored screw on the 3-way switch.
- RB (Right Black): This is the switched hot going from the single pole switch to whatever it controls -- it lands on the single pole switch.
- RW (Right White): This is the neutral out to whatever the single pole switch controls -- it goes into the bundle of white wires with LW.

While you're in there, don't forget to stick a tape flag (use electrical tape for this) on the middle cable's white wire so that the next person working in the box knows its a traveler and not a neutral.  Or, better yet, use color-coded tape flags to mark the wires by function: black for always-hot, red for switched-hot, and say yellow or blue for travellers, for instance.  (You don't need to distinguish the two travellers from each other since they have the same job.)

Comment: And I recommend buying some colored tape and tape-wrapping the wires to label them by function.  Black=always hot, red=switched hot, yellow=both travelers.  (The travelers do the same thing and are interchangeable, so there's no need to distinguish them from each other.)